# Narrator reads hidden elements in scan mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, narrator

I have WPF code, where the narrator reads a hidden toggle button. It reads 'expand/collapse button'. I even set it to collapsed. And set the focusable property to false. None of this works. Is there some property that I can use?

Comment: It's been awhile since I ran into this but experienced a similar scenario where I eventually just moved the functionality out of UI all together but I have seen people do like #4 on [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2014/05/05/solutions-to-some-common-accessibility-issues-found-in-xaml-apps/) since wpf doesn't have AccessibilityView=Raw like UWP does.

Comment: As a test , I was able to customize the AutomationPeer and override the IsControlElementCore() method to return false. And this will hide the element from the Narrator. However in my application , the togglebutton that I need to hide is generated using the ListBox template. And I use the Setter to set the visibility to Collapsed for a specific condition. So if I customize my Control , it will hide all the toggle buttons from the narrator. Is there a work around this?

Comment: By generated using the listbox template, are you maybe talking about a ListBoxItem itself? Or a separate control that's just IN the item? This is a tough one to answer without code to review and I'll be offline soon.

Answer (score 1):

If a button is collapsed the narrator should not read the content. Unfortunately, a bug in the .NET Framework prevents the correct behavior. You can fix it by overriding the IsControlElementCore() method in its automation peer.

details on how to do this: 
https://thinkrethink.net/2019/02/11/wpf-narrator-reads-collapsed-content

Answer (score -1):

you can use the aria-hidden and set is to true to hide elements from the scan mode of narrator.